# MySQL search In multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have 3 tables: cities , areas , sub_locations, I don't know which one the user is searching so I'd like to search in all the tables at once and also I need to somehow indicate is it area or city or sub_location that returned as a result.

tables stucture:

```
Cities:
id int
city_name varChar

Areas:
id int
area_name varChar

Sub_locations:
id int
sub_location_name varChar
```

so only need to search in city_name , area_name and sub_location_name

I'd like to use full text search.Also I use Laravel 4 so you may query in Eloquent. Pls help, never have dealt with that kind of logic before. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like

```
$keyword = $_POST['your_search_input_field'];

$query = "(SELECT city_name FROM Cities WHERE city_name LIKE '%" . 
       $keyword . "%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT area_name FROM Areas WHERE area_name LIKE '%" . 
       $keyword . "%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT sub_location_name FROM Sub_locations WHERE sub_location_name LIKE '%" . 
       $keyword . "%' )";

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Hi , thank you it works, but for some reason it always indicates that it is ['city_name'] even when the results are from Area table, also it doesn't output ids

Comment: is city_name is for sub_location too ? For ids...add like = select id, city_name from Cities....select id, area_name from Areas......select id, sub_location_name from Sub_locations...And echo it along with results...

Comment: thanks , I did a work around , I add a column to each table like 'table_name' to indicate where results are coming from, otherwise for some reason it was always displayed as city, so I just needed to indicate where each result is coming from, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT `city_name` as `area` ,'city' as type FROM `cities` where city_name 
'your like conditions'
union 
select `area_name` as `area`, 'area' as type from `areas` where 'your like conditions'
union
select `sub_location_name` as `area`, 'sublocation' as type where 'your like conditions'
from `Sub_locations`
```

Here you will find results and also sort from which table these results coming from by type  column .